# Syntax error while adding custom scripts to asp.net master page

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to add jQuery and Bootstrap scripts on my master page but it doesn't work, I get a syntax error.

> SCRIPT1002 asp.net can't add any script

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TicketDeskMain.master.cs" Inherits="TicketDesk.TicketDeskMain" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContentPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="AjaxScriptManager" runat="server" />
        <div>....</div>
    </form>

    <ticketDesk:KeepAlive ID="KeepAlive1" runat="server" />
    <ticketDesk:KeepAlive ID="KeepAliveScript" runat="server" />
    </form>

    <script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script> <!-- HERE I've added a script -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have `</form>` twice in your code. Is it normal ?

Comment: If you have found your solution, please add it as an answer, and accepter it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yep, that works quite well so, i've found a solution of that problem

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl(@"~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js") %>"></script> just write this line at the end of masterpage: and in web.config this: <location path="Scripts"> <system.web> <authorization> <allow users="?" /> </authorization> </system.web> </location>
```